# Dailymotion Graph API Search string

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am unable to get Dailymotion Graph API to do a search on a multiple word term. For example:

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos/?search=%22glacier+national+park%22&page=1&limit=3

Will still search on each word separately.

If I &sort=relevance, then it is fine, but if I'd like to sort differently, it will pull titles with only the word "national" in them, and not restrict to the full term.

Their own Graph API tool mimics this:
https://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/explorer#/video/list

It almost seems like it is a bug, but prolly I'm just not finding the right syntax.

TIA!

Comment: hi, this behavior should change in the coming weeks, stay tuned!

Comment: ha! this was my exact same question too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Good news, you can do a search on multiple terms by using **quotes** around words.

Hence your request:

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos/?search=%22glacier+national+park%22&page=1&limit=3

should return what you're looking for!